# Set FALSE to CodeIgniter XSS Clean doesn't work for me

Tags: security, codeigniter, input, xss

If setted FALSE to an input field in CodeIgniter it still is removing some parts of value.
Who can help me?
(I'm Brazilian, my english is poor)

(Why some people do a click -1 vote on my question?)

Comment: In config.php there is general setting as xss_clean. Check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application/config/config.php setting for `$config['global_xss_filtering']` is set to `TRUE`, then the second parameter of `$this->input->post()` (or `get()`, etc.) will NOT have any effect. You must disable the global filtering for the second parameter to have any impact.

Note that this [has been brought up as an issue](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/346), and will hopefully be changed in the relatively near future. We'll see, I guess.